# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Could not find any usable binding services in WSDL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have this problem when trying to access my WSDL

```
    public function send(){

    $options = [
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    ];
    $soap = new \SoapClient('http://localhost:1025/GMService/?wsdl', $options);
    var_dump($soap->__getFunctions());

}
```

[image]

Link in web:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are missing `<wsdl:binding>` tag in your WSDL file, it should look like

```xml
<wsdl:binding name="SomeServiceSOAPBinding" type="tns:SomeService">
```

And then you should also have `<wsdl:service>` tag with `<wsdl:port>`, and some example of it

```xml
    <wsdl:service name="SomeService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:SomeServiceSOAPBinding" name="SomeServicePort">
            <soap:address location="http://127.0.01:1025/SomeServicePort"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```